# Which Hanna-Barbera franchises are featured in "Scoob!"?

Tags: reference, scooby-doo, scoob

I haven’t seen the new Scooby-Doo movie (*Scoob!*), just enough of the trailer to know that Blue Falcon and Dick Dasterly are in it. My question is how many other Hanna-Barbara franchises are there in this movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the cast list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoob!#Cast), Captain Caveman and Dee Dee Sykes from *[Captain Caveman and the Teen Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Caveman_and_the_Teen_Angels)* also appear in the film.

The intention behind *Scoob!* is to set up a shared cinematic universe of Hanna-Barbera properties, similar to the Marvel Cinematic Universe, hence the appearance of several characters from their other franchises.